# How do you build apps for all iOS devices?

Tags: ios, constraints

I have an app that is nearing completion. However, I don't know how to finish it so it will look good on all iOS devices. It's a portrait only app, and it is the same on all devices (bigger screens don't show anything extra or different from smaller devices).

How do I make constraints that will work on all devices? I know there are different size classes that Xcode has, but it seems tedious to go to each class and add specific constraints.

Comment: You shouldn't need different constraints for the different sizes if you want the same layout. That is what autolayout is for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use Autolayout for all resizing of your UI. But if you still want to go with this, I found this thread [What setting determines whether an app gets scaled for iPhone 6 and 6plus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25962940/what-setting-determines-whether-an-app-gets-scaled-for-iphone-6-and-6plus)

Again, try to use Autolayout, add constraints its very easy. If you wish to change your mind go through the tutorial and add constraints https://www.raywenderlich.com/115440/auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-part-1-getting-started-2

Comment: I'm new to Xcode/Swift. How does Autolayout work? Right now, everything in the storyboard was made in the Any/Any Class. Does Autolayout scale it out so that it is the same on all devices, just the bigger screens everything is bigger and the smaller screens everything is smaller? When I put it on my iPad Mini 2, it doesn't fill out. It looks like what is in the storyboard, but not sized to the whole screen.

Comment: You need to add constraints before viewing them on different devices. That is why I added a tutorial in the answer. Go through it and you will learn the basics.